# Should I notify while holding the lock on a condition or after releasing it?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

The [Python `threading` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) lists the following example of a producer:

```
from threading import Condition
cv = Condition()

# Produce one item
with cv:
    make_an_item_available()
    cv.notify()
```

I had to review threading and I looked at [the C++ documentation, which states](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all):

> The notifying thread does not need to hold the lock on the same mutex
>   as the one held by the waiting thread(s); in fact doing so is a
>   pessimization, since the notified thread would immediately block
>   again, waiting for the notifying thread to release the lock.

That would suggest doing something like this:

```
# Produce one item
with cv:
    make_an_item_available()
cv.notify()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't read C++ documentation to understand Python APIs. Per [the actual Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition.notify):

> If the calling thread has not acquired the lock when this method is called, a `RuntimeError` is raised.

Python explicitly requires that the lock be held while `notify`ing.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.  Won't the consumer block immediately then?

Comment: @NeilG: Yes, but that would have happened anyway (most of the time), they need [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL) to even begin execution again, and `notify` doesn't release the GIL. The thread that called `notify` will finish up its time slice (which, assuming they called `notify` at the end of the `with` block for the `Condition`, usually gives it time to release the `Condition`) before releasing the GIL, at which point the `notify`-ed thread wakes, and hopefully acquires both GIL and `Condition`. It may take some time if other threads acquire GIL first.